# Can't get Growl notifications working with growl-rspec gem

Tags: rspec, growl, guard

I have the "guard-rspec" gem installed in my gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem "guard-rspec"
  gem "growl"
end
```

When I run guard, it executes my rspec unit tests and outputs this message at the end:

```
Finished in 2.69 seconds
81 examples, 0 failures, 4 pending
/Users/KevinPang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rspec: No such file or directory - growlnotify --version
```

Note that if I actually type in that path in Terminal (/Users/KevinPang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rspec), it executes rspec:

```
/Users/KevinPang/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rspec
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00003 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out. I forgot to install [**GrowlNotify**](http://growl.info/downloads.php#generaldownloads).

*Note:* ensure that the versions of **Growl** and **GrowlNotify** are matching:

[image: Match Growl and GrowlNotify versions]

Comment: +1, growlnotify as in http://growl.info/downloads.php under General Downloads, I would add. It's not enough to install just "Growl"

Comment: Also, the versions (of Growl and GrowlNotify) need to match.